# How iOS Notifications Work, if App notification setting is set OFF then ON?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to see old notifications in my `iOS` device, if I set the app notification settings from OFF state to ON state?
Say for instance, I have set my App notification settings as "OFF" yesterday where the APP admin has sent custom notification message. Today I noticed that the App Settings are in OFF state. So I changed the settings to ON. Will I get that custom notification now?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible,Once you **de-authorise** any app to send Push Notifications then your device isn't able to receive the notification from that particular app,So you can't find the old notifications.